# How to query tables in a particular schema with less than 100 rows?

Tags: db2

How to query tables in a particular schema with less than 100 rows?

Comment: I think this is the question being asked:How do I get a list of tables in my DB2 database that have 100 or fewer rows?

Answer (score 1):

First do a runstats on your whole schema. Then:

```
select tabname from syscat.tables where card < 100 and tabschema = 'theschema'
```