# I would like to count records in all tables in the schema using SQL for DB2 z/OS v9

Tags: sql, db2, mainframe, zos

I try this statement

```
select schema_name , tabs_name ,
('select count(*) from' || schema_name ||'.'|| tabs_name)
from sysibm.systables
where schema_name = 'Sample'
```

I would like in the string type can be execute string or must be create procedure or any?

```
'select count(*) from' || schema_name ||'.'|| tabs_name
```

Thank you in advance
from Thailand

Comment: You'll have to execute one select statement for each table in the Sample schema. (Some kind of dynamic/script solution probably.)

Comment: Could you please raise example some dynamic/script please ?

Comment: If your table statistics are up-to-date, it looks like this [might be in the syscat tables already](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5705139/812837).  Otherwise, yes you need a dynamic statement; [this looks like a good starting point](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27441641/812837).  What do you want this information for?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, NUMBER_ROWS from qsys2.systablestat
Where TABLE_NAME = 'Sample'
```